# How to get Azure App service audit Logs (not using App insights)

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

My requirement is under a particular subscription, i am expected to get logs of an Azure App service which would contain below log data like...

Headers,
Parameters,
Endpoints,
Request Payload(full),
Response payload(full),
HTTP response code,
Request ID.

I have tried using Azure Monitor REST API, but was not able to capture the above log elements in it
Kindly suggest, if there is any way to get it done

Comment: Any update on this issue , is this log what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could go to `Diagnose and solve problems` under your app, then choose `Diagnostics Tools` and there is a diagnostic tool **Collect a Network Trace**. Then choose collect Network Trace. After this finish, it will show you a zip file link you could download it.

[image]

The below is my cap file, suppose this is what you want.

[image]